# Match calendar days with corresponding overwork rates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have certain conditions for work rates. For example standard day is 8 hours (MO, TU, WE, TH, FR), extra hours are cost*1,5. Lets say cost is 50. I would like to count them based on week days MO, TU, WE, TH, FR, SA, SU.

How formula should look like for this matter? In my example result should be:

```
MO -> (50*8)+(50*1,5)+(50*1,5)
TU -> (50*8)
WE -> (50*8)+(50*1,5)+(50*1,5)
TH -> (50*8)+(50*1,5)+(50*1,5)
FR -> (50*8)+(50*1,5)+(50*1,5)
SA -> SKIP
SU -> SKIP

After all these calculations, sum of all of these
```

I would like to make it work for the whole range somehow so basically compare row 11 to row 9 and do certain calculations based on matches. My real range is `=$O$11:$BQS$41`

The other way is extract extra hours from the row. They are all over 8 a day. So here we have 2 hours each day except TU. So the calculation would be `8*5+8*50*1,5`

Comment: How do you get value in row 9? Manual typing or with formula? You can use 'if statement' that depends on the day of the week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the easiest if you just add a few more rows.

You need to have for each day:

- rate for regular hours (NR);
- rate for extra hours (XR);
- number of worked normal hours (WN);
- number of worked extra hours (WX);

Once you have these, you calculate the payment easily:

```
TOTAL = NR * WN + XR * WX
```

---

You can make it more complicated, to specify for each day the maximum number of normal hours (WNMax) - but the formula gets more complicated.

```
if WNMax < WN print error
else TOTAL = NR * WN + XR * WX
```